# Azure databricks workspaces - grouping

Tags: azure-databricks

In my company under a certain subscription we have about 15 databricks instances created. I am part of system-admin group and have access to all of it. If I launch a specific workspace say Sales-Dev, in the UI I see a drop down where I can switch to Sales-QA or Sales-Prod.
Similarly some other DB workspaces are grouped. But I am not able to find out how exactly this drop-down is populated to only show Sales-DEV,Sales-QA, Sales-Prod but exclude say HR-Dev, HR-Prod which is in same account and I have same access to.

Comment: The drop-down menu in the workspace UI that allows you to switch between different workspaces is populated based on the groups that the workspaces belong to. It is likely that the workspaces that are grouped together in the drop-down menu are account groups rather than workspace-local groups. To confirm this, you can check the group settings on the Azure Databricks workspace admin settings page.